# Doing git commit --amend by mistake and easy fix

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I did a commit in my local branch.
Then I realised that I committed a file by mistake.
So I did:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git restore --staged filename.txt
```

Then by mistake I did `git commit --amend`
I realised that my changes would be merged to the previous commit so when the editor was opened I removed the messages but because I pressed save instead of quit my changes were merged to the previous commit.

Is there a way to fix the mistake or I need to do it manually? In case it helps the previous commit is a merge commit and `git show` does not show any code for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-commit%5D+undo+amend

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done anything in the repo since then, you can just

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

to reset `HEAD` back to the previous commit, i.e. the one where `HEAD` was before the `commit --amend`.

If you are unsure, you can investigate the reflog of `HEAD`:

```
git reflog show HEAD
```

Find the commit you want to go to. It should be the one that says

```
reset: moving to HEAD~1
```

Note that the `HEAD~1` in this text does not mean the *current* `HEAD~1`, but is the literal text taken from the command that caused the mentioned `reset`; it is the one that you note in the question!